# How to Deploy a C#.net  project in Visual studio 2010 (ultimate)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-deployment

solution is developed for  x86 platform and framework 3.5...
i need to include pre-request setups  in my offline project ...dot net frame work 3.5 , sql server compact server sp 2,windows installer 3.1 are the pre-request that the setup should check for and install if not installed in target machine...how to create setup with pre-request setups ?
Builded successfully...when i select pre-request without framework 3.5...... error occours only when i select framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the Launch conditions editor for specifying prerequisites on client machine. And you can package the rest and deploy it using one of two approaches: ClickOnce or Windows Installer. More on this here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx

Comment: okay,i choose Publish a ClickOnce Application...i don't know how to include pre-request setup files(dot net frame work 3.5 , sql server compact server sp 2,windows installer 3.1) in the installer ???

Comment: I am sure whether you want to mention those as pre-requisites or you want to bundle them with your setup project. 

If it is the first case, then use the Prerequisites button and specify the requirements as .net framework 3.5 and so on.

If it is the second case, then use the Custom actions editor and include the installs for those software. 

These links may help you:

http://www.roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0121.html

http://windowsclient.net/blogs/forumsclickoncesetupdeployment/default.aspx?PageIndex=174

Comment: "Error 1 The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet.msp' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information. C:\Users\AnAnd\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Setup2\Setup2\Setup2.vdproj"

Comment: Builded successfully...when i select pre-request without framework 3.5...... error occours only when i select framework 3.5...

Comment: Still there is a error when we include pre-request as framework 3.5 in visual studio 2010...... i found a solution here..http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/997550a7-1d5c-403b-9271-65d1daf67d83

Comment: Problem Solved...... Builded successfully even with framework 3.5 in pre-request....!!!